# How to implement a compareTo method using the Token as a parameter

Tags: java

I don't know what my professor means when he asks for

A String that contains a token. I did it as follows:

```
String input;
String[] token=input.split(" ");
```

int compareTo(BSTNode) – Compare the this object to the parametric object. First, compare the String members of the objects; if they are unequal, then return the appropriate value. If the String 0members are equal, then compare the int members and return the appropriate value.

My compareTo method looks like this.

```
public int compareTO(BSTNode token){
  if(this.token.equals(token.BSTNode.getToken())){
     if(this.count==count.BSTNode.getCount()){
        return 1;
     }
     else{
        return 0;
     }
     return 1;
  }
  else{
     return 0;
  }
}
```

I am not sure if anything I am doing is right on this

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, in parts yes.

A compareTo is usually used to put things in order, so you don't want to just return 0 or 1. If you have myObject.compareTo(anotherObject), then the convention is to return 0 if they match, a negative number if myObject occurs before anotherOBject and a positive number if myObject occurs after anotherObject.

So if our objects were Strings, then:

```
"A".compareTo("A") = 0,
"A".compareTo("B") = -1,
"B".compareTo("A") = 1.
```

They might not be -1 and +1, they could be any negative or positive. This was for example only!

Your idea with the "token" is on the right track. A token is just a fancy way of saying a part that you are interested in. So in a sentence, a "token" could be a word. In an equation, it might be a term.

Finally, this should be easy for you to implement if you are using Strings - they have a compareTo already implemented! You can just call the ready-made one.

Here is a whole stack of code to demonstrate. In this case, the class BSTNode doesn't really add anything to the raw strings, but it helps give the idea. Notice that the capitals are placed before the lowercase, as this is the default ordering of Strings. Also, see that there is a second compareTo method. It works just as well as the first, though the numbers returned are differed. Finally, notice I implemented the Comparable interface. This is so that sorting will work easily.

```
public class BSTNode implements Comparable<BSTNode> {

    public String node;

    public BSTNode(String node) {
        this.node = node;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "This is the original string is it not?";

        // Tokenize and make nodes
        String[] tokens = string.split(" ");
        BSTNode[] nodes = new BSTNode[tokens.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            nodes[i] = new BSTNode(tokens[i]);
        }

        // Original
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Unsorted " + i + ": " + nodes[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // Compare two nodes
        System.out.println("Node[0] compared to Node[1] = "
                + nodes[0].compareTo(nodes[1]));
        System.out.println("Node[1] compared to Node[0] = "
                + nodes[1].compareTo(nodes[0]));
        System.out.println("Node[1] compared to Node[5] = "
                + nodes[1].compareTo(nodes[5]));
        System.out.println();

        // Sort (only possible thanks to compareTo)
        Arrays.sort(nodes);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Sorted   " + i + ": " + nodes[i]);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(BSTNode t) {
        return this.node.compareTo(t.node);
    }

    public int compareTo2(BSTNode t) {
        String a = node;
        String b = t.node;

        if (a.compareTo(b) < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a.compareTo(b) == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BSTNode{" + "node=" + node + '}';
    }
}
```